Using Bicep to enable the calling functions of MSTeams channel in Azure Bot Services
I have a Microsoft Teams bot App, and I plan to use Teams Toolkit CLI v3 for provision Azure Resource, one is callingbot support for the Teams app. I try to implement the function by bicep.
There are my azurebot.bicep and azurebot.parameters.json
The azurebot.bicep file

@maxLength(32)
@minLength(4)
@description('Used to generate names for all resources in this file')
param resourceBaseName string

@maxLength(42)
param botDisplayName string

param botServiceName string = resourceBaseName
param botServiceSku string
param botAadAppClientId string
param botAppDomain string

// Register your web service as a bot with the Bot Framework
resource botService 'Microsoft.BotService/botServices@2022-09-15' = {
  kind: 'azurebot'
  location: 'global'
  name: botServiceName
  properties: {
    displayName: botDisplayName
    endpoint: 'https://${botAppDomain}/api/messages'
    msaAppId: botAadAppClientId
  }
  sku: {
    name: botServiceSku
  }
}

// Connect the bot service to Microsoft Teams
resource botServiceMsTeamsChannel 'Microsoft.BotService/botServices/channels@2022-09-15' = {
  parent: botService
  location: 'global'
  name: 'MsTeamsChannel'
  properties: {
    channelName: 'MsTeamsChannel'
    isEnabled: true
    acceptedTerms: true
    enableCalling: true
    callingWebhook: 'https://${botAppDomain}/api/callback'
    deploymentEnvironment: 'CommercialDeployment'
  }
}

The azurebot.parameters.json

{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
      "resourceBaseName": {
        "value": "My_BotService_${{RESOURCE_SUFFIX}}"
      },
      "botServiceSku": {
        "value": "${{BOT_SERVICE_SKU}}"
      },
      "botDisplayName": {
        "value": "My bot for MSTeams"
      },
      "botAadAppClientId": {
        "value": "${{BOT_ID}}"
      },
      "botAppDomain": {
        "value": "${{BOT_DOMAIN}}"
      }
    }
}

the Calling page of Azure Resource
Teams Toolkit CLI runs success, but the Calling function cannot be configured as script.
I also try the 2023-09-15-preview version, it is still failed to configure Calling.
I can't fix it and understand what I'm doing wrong.

As Microsoft docs, resource format is defined as
resource symbolicname 'Microsoft.BotService/botServices/channels@2022-09-15' = {
  parent: resourceSymbolicName
  etag: 'string'
  kind: 'string'
  location: 'string'
  name: 'string'
  properties: {
    etag: 'string'
    location: 'string'
    channelName: 'string'
    // For remaining properties, see Channel objects
  }
  sku: {
    name: 'string'
  }
  tags: {
    {customized property}: 'string'
  }
}

and MSTeamsChannel is defined as
{
  channelName: 'MsTeamsChannel'
  properties: {
    acceptedTerms: bool
    callingWebhook: 'string'
    deploymentEnvironment: 'string'
    enableCalling: bool
    incomingCallRoute: 'string'
    isEnabled: bool
  }
}

It cannot be added any key-value pair into properties after name: 'MsTeamsChannel' directly, we should re-defined the children node named properties after channelName: 'MsTeamsChannel', it is means we need define the properties for MsTeamsChannel for channel only.
It's confusing and I made this mistake, so fixed by below:
// Connect the bot service to Microsoft Teams
resource botServiceMsTeamsChannel 'Microsoft.BotService/botServices/channels@2022-09-15' = {
  parent: botService
  location: 'global'
  name: 'MsTeamsChannel'
  properties: {
    channelName: 'MsTeamsChannel'
    properties: {
      acceptedTerms: true
      callingWebhook: 'https://${botAppDomain}/api/callback'
      deploymentEnvironment: 'CommercialDeployment'
      enableCalling: true
//      incomingCallRoute: 'https://${botAppDomain}/api/callback'
      isEnabled: true
    }
  }
}


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
